# Is it normal for SFSafariViewController to "forget" visited links after being dismissed?

Tags: ios, css, hyperlink, safari, sfsafariviewcontroller

I develop a mobile app using SFSafariViewController to present a website, wherein visited links are styled using the CSS :visited pseudo-class (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited).

As long as the user remains within a single SFSafariViewController session, styling visited links works fine. But as soon as the user exits back to the app, SFSafariViewController appears to "forget" which links the user had visited, such that upon returning to the site within SFSafariViewController, none of the previously visited links trigger the :visited pseudo-class, are are thus not styled as visited links.

Is this normal behavior for SFSafariViewController? Chrome Custom Tabs, used in the Android version of the same app, exhibits what I would consider "normal" behavior by remembering visited links between its session on the site in question, as does the Safari mobile browser on the same site.

I have Googled this problem and have come up empty. Of course, having worked with SFSafariViewController, I have also thoroughly read Apple's developer documentation on SFSafariViewController.

Answer (score 0):

The user's activity and interaction with SFSafariViewController are not visible to your app, which cannot access AutoFill data, browsing history, or website data  [(Overview)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller?language=objc).

Comment: Yes, we know this. I'm not needing to share data between SFSafariViewController and the app. I just need SFSafariViewController to remember what links the user has visited :-)

Comment: Is it not the same that browsing history?